# PHP 64 bit - Teradata ODBC driver failure - system error 126 'specified module cannot be found' -

Tags: php, odbc, 64-bit, teradata, windows-server-2012

I have installed PHP 5.6.30 64 bit on Windows Server 2012 along with Teradata ODBC driver.

Whenever I test the PHP connection I receive an error

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 126: The specified module could not be found. (Teradata, C:\Program Files\Teradata\Client\15.00\ODBC Driver for Teradata nt-x8664\Lib\tdata32.dll)., SQL state IM003 in SQLConnect

EDIT: C:\Program Files\Teradata\Client\15.00\ODBC Driver for Teradata nt-x8664\Lib\tdata32.dll does definitely exist on that specific path. Also, using tdxodbc.exe to test the ODBC connection works normally using tdata32.dll, so it appears to be some issue with PHP.

I have installed Teradata ODBC via GSS > ICU > ODBC from the Utilities package based on a related thread however still experiencing the same error. I can make a successful 32-bit ODBC connection via SQL assistant. I have tried a DSN / DSN-less ODBC connection via PHP but same error occurs.

I have been unable to find any clear indication of what the issue is - any idea?

Comment: Please state the obvious... Does `C:\Program Files\Teradata\Client\15.00\ODBC Driver for Teradata nt-x8664\Lib\tdata32.dll` exist or not? The `nt-x8664` seems kind of suspicious; and I would expect `nt-x86_64` or `nt-x86-64` or `nt-x64`.

Comment: Edited to confirm the file is definitely there on that path

Comment: Please check your system's PATH variable. It could be there is not an entry for the 64 bit ODBC, or it could be pointing to an older version if you recently upgraded. There should be entry like `C:\Program Files\Teradata\Client\15.00\bin`

Comment: PATH variables were correct as well.... ultimately I uninstalled everything, deleted all remaining references still found in Registry & PATH (weird that I might even need to do that), re-installed just the ODBC driver without any other utility, restarted the server.... voila it works